# Which module could produce this tag-cloud image?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, tag-cloud

Is there a drupal module that could produce an image like this. I think it's some sort of a tag cloud or something.

[alt text http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/2544/screenshot199.jpg](http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/2544/screenshot199.jpg)

Comment: Questioon is not programming related, maybe http://doctype.com or http://superuser.com are better places for general Drupal support.

Comment: @berkes Web development is not just about writing code, especially when using a modular CMS like drupal (as opposed to building a site from scratch). Since choosing the right modules is one of your development tasks, this question is still web development, and therefore a question for other developers and belongs here. I wouldn't trust a non-developer's answer on this since they're not experienced enough.

Comment: I do agree, partly, but in Drupal there are many consulting questions and -related tasks. Whether or not that is called webdevelopment makes it not more or less "programming related". The FAQ gives no exact definition, so you question was not entirely our of place. But IMHO stackoverflow is about programming (for Drupal) while drupal.org is about all the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

http://sudosys.be/?q=drupal_tag_cloud

Also check out http://drupal.org/project/tagadelic

Comment: Does tagadelic produce text that is vertical like the image above? Tagadelic produces a tag cloud but perhaps not as "involved" as above -- simple sizing between different tags. Has tagadelic added some features?

Comment: tagadelic has no such feature, but is themable. You would be able to pull the output of tagadelic (or its API's) trough a library, to create tag clouds like you want.